# Margin doesn't center

Tags: html, css, center, margin

I am currently working on my portfolio website and so far. But now 
I am having problem to center the "about me" page but i think i made a mistake somewhere because it doesn't do what i want.

Html:

```
<div class="pageAbout">

        <div id="icon">
            <img src="images/iconAbout.png" />
        </div>

        <div id="infoLeft">
            <h3>Name</h3>
                <p>Jeffrey van der Heijden</p>
            <h3>Birthday</h3>
                <p>-</p>
            <h3>Hobbies</h3>
                <p>hanging around with friends and family</p>
        </div>

        <div id="avatar">
            <img src="images/avatarMe.png" />
        </div>

        <div id="infoRight">
            <h3>Place of birth</h3>
                <p>Eindhoven</p>
            <h3>Phone</h3>
                <p>-</p>
            <h3>Email</h3>
                <p>-</p>
        </div>
</div>`
```

CSS:

```
.pageAbout{
width: 100%;
height: auto;
background-color: #e5e5e5;
padding-top: 1%;
} 

h3{
font-family: Aller_regular;
font-size: 16px;
} 

p{
font-family: Aller_regular;
font-size: 14px;
margin: 2% 0px;
}

#infoLeft{
width: 12%;
height: auto;
float: left;
margin-top: 2%;
text-align: right;
}

#avatar{
width: 18%;
height: auto;
float: left;
margin-top: 2%;
text-align: center;
}

#infoRight{
width: 12%;
height: auto;
float: left;
margin-top: 2%;
text-align: left;
}
```

so What I want is.

`infoLeft` needs to be on the `left` side of the `avatar` and `infoRight` on the `right` side of the `avatar` image and the image needs to be in the center of the page.

I hope i gave given enough and the right information.

Thanks.

Comment: it is happening because you are using `float:left` in all the three classes `infoLeft` , `infoRight` and `avatar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise you to improve your boxing and get into the **CSS3 flexbox**!

1. Let the first icon div apart by creating another block
   .flex-center for centering the content.
2. The same inside for the
   avatar, just to center it vertically.
3. Then, move the width: 18%
   to the level of #avatar-container.
4. Then add the correct flex
   properties to flex-center and avatar-container.
5. Also, remove the auto height.

   ```
   <div class="flex-center">
       <div id="infoLeft" >
           <h3>Name</h3>
               <p>Jeffrey van der Heijden</p>
           <h3>Birthday</h3>
               <p>-</p>
           <h3>Hobbies</h3>
               <p>hanging around with friends and family</p>
       </div>

       <div id="avatar-container">
           <div id="avatar">
               <img src="images/avatarMe.png" />
           </div>
       </div>

       <div id="infoRight" >
           <h3>Place of birth</h3>
               <p>Eindhoven</p>
           <h3>Phone</h3>
               <p>-</p>
           <h3>Email</h3>
               <p>-</p>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

and

```
.pageAbout{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    padding-top: 1%;
} 

h3{
    font-family: Aller_regular;
    font-size: 16px;
} 

p{
    font-family: Aller_regular;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 2% 0px;
}

#infoLeft{
    width: 12%;
    /* height: auto; */
    /*float: left;*/
    margin-top: 2%;
    text-align: right;
}

#avatar{
    width: 18%;
    /* height: auto; */
    /*float: left;*/
    margin-top: 2%;
    text-align: center;
}

#infoRight{
    width: 12%;
    /* height: auto; */
    /*float: left;*/
    margin-top: 2%;
    text-align: left;
}

#avatar-container {
  width: 18%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

}

.flex-center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so these are the mistakes:

1. You don't need any default styles like: `width: 100%;` and `height: auto;`.
2. Give `overflow: hidden;` to clear the `float`s.
3. Change the `width`s of the `info-*` and `#image` to sum up to `100%`.
4. Align the `#avatar img` centered by using `text-align: center;`.
5. Create a *faux margin* for the `#avatar` to look like it is vertically centered.

**Snippet**

```css
.pageAbout {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  padding-top: 1%;
  overflow: hidden;
} 

h3 {
  font-family: Aller_regular;
  font-size: 16px;
} 

p{
  font-family: Aller_regular;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 2% 0px;
}

#infoLeft{
  width: 30%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 2%;
  text-align: right;
}

#avatar {
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10%;
  text-align: center;
}

#avatar img {
  display: inline-block;
}

#infoRight{
  width: 30%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 2%;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="pageAbout">

  <div id="icon">
    <img src="images/iconAbout.png" />
  </div>

  <div id="infoLeft">
    <h3>Name</h3>
    <p>Jeffrey van der Heijden</p>
    <h3>Birthday</h3>
    <p>-</p>
    <h3>Hobbies</h3>
    <p>hanging around with friends and family</p>
  </div>

  <div id="avatar">
    <img src="images/avatarMe.png" />
  </div>

  <div id="infoRight">
    <h3>Place of birth</h3>
    <p>Eindhoven</p>
    <h3>Phone</h3>
    <p>-</p>
    <h3>Email</h3>
    <p>-</p>
  </div>
</div>
```